# Code works on API 8 and can't on API 9 or 10

Tags: android

For some reason my code works perfectly for Froyo(API 8) but gives me a Stopped Unexpectedly/Force Close error when I try to run it on API 9 or 10, AVD and phones give me the same error message. Any idea as to why? 
My code for review:

All pages look similar to ViewActivity.java. only difference id the drawable called.

ViewActivity.java:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class ViewActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //creates view
    TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(this);
    //sets image
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.largeimage1);
    img.setImageBitmap(image);
    img.setMaxZoom(3f);
    setContentView(img); 
}
    //Creates the options menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.echooptions, menu);
    return true;
}
//Starts the chosen menu activity
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.back_item:
        Intent intentb = new Intent(this, page16.class);
        startActivity(intentb);
        return true;
    case R.id.next_item:
        Intent intentn = new Intent(this, page2.class);
        startActivity(intentn);
        return true;
    case R.id.about_menu_item:
        Intent intenta = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intenta);
        return true;
    case R.id.tablecontents:
        return true;
    case R.id.page1:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        return true;
    case R.id.page2:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, page2.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
    }
```

TouchImageView.java:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.PointF;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;


public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                        float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                        if (scaleWidth < width) {
                            deltaX = 0;
                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom); 
                        } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                            deltaY = 0;
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);
                        } else {
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) { 
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x)
{
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = (float)Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX =  (float)width / (float)bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float)height / (float)bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float)height - (scale * (float)bmHeight) ;
    redundantXSpace = (float)width - (scale * (float)bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float)2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InstantiationException: mil.Army.page2` implies it can't create an instance of class `page2`.  I think this is usually thrown when you try to instantiate an abstract class or interface.  According to [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/326160/java/java/Reasons-java-lang-InstantiationException) it can be thrown because the class doesn't have a default (zero-argument) constructor.  I don't know why it would work only on API 8 since this seems to be a Java issue, but it seems to be a possible cause.

EDIT:  May also try to simply rebuild the project.  In Eclipse, just clean it by going to `Project->Clean`.

EDIT:  I also came across this as well that seems to b related:

[Why do I get an InstantiationException if I try to start a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176255/why-do-i-get-an-instantiationexception-if-i-try-to-start-a-service)

Comment: It could be you're hard-coding a label rather than using a String resource according to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740893/android-search-activty-not-starting

Comment: Still getting this error: '10-28 14:45:17.827: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(774): 8420100-byte external allocation too large for this process.
10-28 14:45:17.851: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(774): VM won't let us allocate 8420100 bytes' Thanks for the help so far DeeV.

Comment: That message can mean that you're allocating an array or object that's just way to big (possibly an image).  You need to figure out where you're allocating large chunks at a time and see if you can cut it.  I wish I could tell you why this is only affecting later APIs though.  Theoretically, if a program works in API 8, it would work in API 9+ too.

Comment: One reason I dislike theory, it usually doesn't work that way...but thanks for the help if I figure it out I'll post as to what I did to fix it. Thanks for your time DeeV.

Comment: Well, I don't know what the functional differences are between those APIs.  I'm thinking it could be similar to the recent API 14 problems people have in which the IDs generated in the R file are no longer declared `final`.  They did it so ID numbers to be altered to prevent collisions with shared libraries.  99% of the time, it affects absolutely nothing.  However, Java `switch` statements that used IDs as keys no longer compile and everyone had to convert them to if-else statements.  I'm just not 100% sure that's the reason.

Comment: It looks like it was caused by my images being loaded. I changed them all to .gifs which are smaller than the .jpegs they were and now I can get to more of my pages every time. I thank you for giving me that idea as it seems to be the fix. That's interesting about API 14, and the switch/if-else. I'll keep an eye on that. Thanks again for all your help.