# IntentService and AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027147/android-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-the-service)

I can't find a way to start IntentService from AlarmManager. It is simple for normal service (add it to the manifest, then wrap it up in Intent), but I can't make it work with IntentService - app keeps crashing with "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service". There is nothing wrong with the IntentService itself (1 line of code). Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no problem to fire IntentService from AlarmManager, and I did it more than once. In the case of IntentService I met cases where a few lines of code were enough to make the problem.

Make sure your IntentService has a constructor like that:

```
    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }
```

Because alarm manager will try to instantiate it with no parameters, and the original IntentService constructor [receives String as a parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#IntentService%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That works. My environment keeps generating the constructor with the parameter, which caused the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome, good night.