# IntentService RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, runtimeexception, intentservice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027147/android-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-the-service)

Problem: starting an `IntentService` generates a `RuntimeException`.

I'm clueless. If you need more info, just ask. Log:

```
D/dalvikvm( 6839): newInstance failed: no <init>()
D/AndroidRuntime( 6839): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 6839): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service org.xyz.android.service.MyService: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.xyz.android.service.MyService
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1929)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.xyz.android.service.MyService
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1926)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6839):    ... 10 more
```

This code calls the service (it's being called from a `ContentProvider`):

```
Intent i = new Intent(
        getContext(),
        MyService.class);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_MISSING, missingMonths);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_URI, uri);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_START, startTime);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_END, endTime);
    getContext().startService(i);
```

And this is the `IntentService` relevant code blocks (there are only two methods. Besides the asynctask itself, of course):

```
public MyService(String name) {
    super("MyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // ... do stuff
        new DownloaderTask().execute(missingMonths);
}
```

Comment: did you describe it in manifest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to be missing the zero-argument public constructor. Delete the `String name` from your current constructor (since you're not using it anyway), and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that one.

Comment: Can you specify why ? as it was comming default   there