# GCMIntentReceivier not work when it is not in root package

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google GCMIntentService instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332034/google-gcmintentservice-instantiate)

I tried to work with `GoogleCloud` for android. I followed the tutorial, and it works fine. But when I try to put `GCMIntentService.java` class in some package(not root) it simply can't find it(no errors, just can't get RegID).

in Manifest file I have specified it:

```
<service android:name=".service.GCMIntentService" />
```

Rest everything is unchanged.

Thanks.

Comment: Finally resolved! According to google docs, if you want to put GCMIntentService.java to other package(not root) or to rename it, you also need to implement child class of GCMBroadcastReceiver. And override it method called getGCMIntentServiceClassName(). Also in Manifest change receiver name to yours. That's all.

Comment: The problem was also described and resolved [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332034/google-gcmintentservice-instantiate