# Android IntentService Instantiation error

Tags: android, runtime-error, intentservice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027147/android-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-the-service)

I am downloading my data using IntentService. My IntentService class definition is as follows:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService{
super("DownloadService");
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //download tasks...
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<appilcation>
<service android:name="DownloadService"/>
..
..
..
</application>
```

LauncherActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ..
        ..
        ..
    Intent dwnldService = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
    startService(dwnldService);
}
```

But still I am getting this error:

```
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.app.android.DowloadService: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.app.android.DowloadService; no empty constructor
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2237)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.app.android.DowloadService; no empty constructor
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-13 08:57:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2234)
```

Comment: Does your manifest.xml really say `<appilcation>` or did you actually type it anew instead of just copying it into your question?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
public DownloadService() {
    super("Download service");
}
```

Try adding this to your service.

Comment: Just adding a space to the string! What difference is it going to make?

Comment: I got it... My constructor included String name in the parameters. It shouldn't be there. And it doesn't matter if we give a space in parameter of super.

Comment: Yes... Change the constructer from `public              DownloadService(String name) {super(name);}  to public DownloadService() { super("DownloadService");}`

Answer (score 2):

**Add default constructor with super("name") calling in your class**

```
public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
 }
```